# Android : Unhide a snapped toolbar programmatically

Tags: android, scroll, hide, toolbar

The toolbar is hidden when the screen is scrolled :

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">
```

How can I unhide it programmatically (i.e. when I click a button) ?

Comment: Add full layout

Comment: and also mainActivity

Answer (score 1):

Probably you wrap `Toolbar` inside `AppBarLayout`. In that case you have to get `AppBarLayout.LayoutParams` and need to invoke `setScrollFlags()` with `0` to stop the scroll. Check below:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of them
1. without animation
 getSupportActionBar().show();
2. With animation
toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();